# deactivate mnemonic for JButton

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, mnemonics

I need help to deactivate the Mnemonic for JButton. Actually I am using 3rd party API, which they set mnemonic as "Alt C". So I want to remove this mnemonic and wants to set nothing (i.e wants to remove the mnemonic) for this compButton.

```
    // Alt + 'C' selects the comp.
     compButton.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_C);
```

Answer (score 4):

How about using the `compButton.setMnemonic(0);`

**edit:**

I saw `javax/swing/AbstractButton.java`:

```
/**
 * Returns key bindings associated with this object
 *
 * @return the key bindings, if supported, of the object;
 * otherwise, null
 * @see AccessibleKeyBinding
 * @since 1.4
 */
public AccessibleKeyBinding getAccessibleKeyBinding() {
    int mnemonic = AbstractButton.this.getMnemonic();
    if (mnemonic == 0) {
        return null;
    }
    return new ButtonKeyBinding(mnemonic);
}
```

Therefore, `compButton.setMnemonic(0);` looks even better than `compButton.setMnemonic(-1);`.

Comment: 0 is actually defined for KeyEvent. I would suggest using a negative value if you want to take this approach.